# How to split a form with validation on several pages

Tags: blazor

I have a server-side Blazor app with a EditForm and a DataAnnotationValidator for validation. I want to split the form on several pages with a Back and Forward button on each one and the forward button should validate only the fields on the current page.

Currently I achieved the form split with a switch statement that checks a "Page" variable. If the forward button is clicked, Page gets incremented and after a page rerender, other fields are shown. But I can't validate only one page, because the validator validates the whole model and so I can't differentiate between a valid and an invalid page.

Do I have to use an EditForm for each page with a validator on a sub-model that has only the fields of the current page or is there another, more elegant solution.

Comment: How did you eventually solve this problem? Do you have a single form or multiple forms?

Comment: I think I used FluentValidator to validate only the fields that are on the shown page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out Isaacs answer, or you can go the other route and create different edit forms for every tab. I don’t know which would be best. Check out this article put out by Chris Sainty on fluent validation.

[Article Here](https://chrissainty.com/using-fluentvalidation-for-forms-validation-in-razor-components/)

Theoretically, you could create a validator for each tab that only handles its own tab validation

Comment: Welcome to SO! Answers based on live links are risky as they can disappears. Add some content of your link just in case it dead.

Comment: I tried Fluent Validation and it is nearly what I had hoped for. The only problem I have is, when I click the button for next page, the validation occurs and I only change the page if the inputs are valid. But if I didn't enter something in a required field, I don't get a ValidationMessage. I only get the ValidationMessage, if I entered something. So the ValidateField method works, but the ValidationMessageStore of the ValidateModel method seems to be broken or I don't know how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can implement that using Templated Components. [Here is a link](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/f10a552e1761ff759b1631d81a4428c3) to a TabSet sample created by Steve Anderson which you can emulate to design your entry form. The sample is relatively old, and you may have to tweak it ( namespaces, name of life cycle events, etc.). You don't have to design your entry form as a TabSet, though many do that, but the principle is the same. You display one tab and hide the others... that is, moving from one page or section to the next.

Note: Your entry form remains on the same Page (Component Page, a Component with the @page directive and route template). You do not create a Page for each part of the entry form as you may have done...

I believe you don't have to add an EditForm to each Tab (partial part of your entry form). You can wrap the TabSet (or whatever you call this component) with the EditForm Component.

In order to partially validate your data entry form, you'll need to perform the validation manually, by calling EditContext.Validate method.

It seems to me that this can work great. Please report of your advances. I'm curious if my suggestion are really usual.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I tried the TabSet, but I like the separate pages more. I validate my model now manually with Fluent Validator, as recommended in the answer below. But I still have a small problem with the ValidationMessage (see answer below, for more information)

Comment: The TabSet sample was intended to demonstrate how to handle group of content (fragment html and text, etc.), how to move from one group to another, and so on. The TabSet is located on a single Component page (a component with @page directive and route template), and it is made of Tab components, arranged by css and and manipulated by C#. You can rearrange the Tab components in a different way by changing the values of one or two css rules, so they would look like pages to you. Note that you're using Blazor; this is a SPA .There are no pages to move from and forth.This is not Razor pages or mvc

Comment: I know that Blazor is a SPA and with different pages I meant one page with different content that gets displayed based on an int variable "Page" and a switch statement. This works fine in my case and thus I don;t bother with the TabSet. The only problem left is that the ValidationMessages are only shown, when a field gets validated, but not when the whole model or a submodel gets validated (which I do when I click next to get on the next "page").

Answer (score 0):

I am facing that problem but achieved in jquery by individual or group of controls validation with in a form. But blazor not support because of it validates only all the fields. If want to validate a specific control, its not possible.

Ericgrantholland answered this question by doing separate form. It is a good idea. This is very useful. But individual field validation uses many other places like i want to click a check box button named 'Same as Billing address' it will fill the data of Billing address control to Shipping Address control with validation task. How do i achieve this through blazor?

If blazor support individual field validation, like the code $('#ShippingInfo').validate().element('#ShippingAddress_StateID'), i can achieve any thing.

Comment: Check out [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/). With FluentValidation you can write your own validators.